# Statement level Trigger or Row Level Trigger

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

Which trigger to use - Statement or Row level?
If I use row level trigger , how to restrict it to insert data in tracking table only once for a group of entries in VALUES table

Database Schema -

ITEM_VERSIONS TABLE - Item_id,Version id,start_version_id,end_version_id
ITEM_VALUES_TABLE-  Value Id, Value, Item_id, Start_version , End Version

Each time an item is created : 
ITEM_VERSIONS TABLE - This table stores all the information of Item Versions.
For 1 item version, it has 1 row.

ITEM_VALUES_TABLE - This has all the values info .
So for 1 item , this table has 15-20 rows for each value attribute. Lets say Item_date , color etc

I want to create a trigger on ITEM_VALUES_TABLE and insert the version id in the tracking table.

To get version id, I have to use ITEM_VERSIONS TABLE to get the version id of the item and then update in the tracking table

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: I am not sure that I understand exactly what you are asking (sample data and expected results would likely be helpful).  Assuming that you need access to the values in the row(s) that are changing, though, you'd need a row-level trigger.  Statement level triggers cannot access row-level information for the rows that are changing.

Comment: This smacks of the Entity-Attribute-Value model, which is definitely [a SQL anti-pattern](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/): it makes it easy to store data but it's a nightmare to retrieve it. Adding version tracking to EAV is a nice twist, which will make it even more horrible to use. Are you really sure what benefits you're going to get from all this work? As opposed to (say) using a normalized data model? Or JSON or XML?

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for the reply . Yes I need to access the row level information. So I am going with the row level triggers.

Comment: I did not understand the problem correctly in the beginning. There is one more unique column with each inserts in VALUES table that I need to track in the audit table.  So now with this requirement , I cannot group the trigger to insert once and hence going with the row level triggers